# How do I add a dot inside the zeros on the date?

Tags: formatting, datetime

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% dot with zero
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\pmzerodot}{%
  \nfss@text{%
\sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% math axis
\sbox2{0}%
\sbox4{0\/}%
\ooalign{%
  0\cr
  \hidewidth
  \kern\dimexpr\wd4-\wd2\relax % compensate for slanted fonts
  \raise\dimexpr(\ht2-\dp2)/2-\ht0\relax\hbox{%
    \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\relax
      \mathversion{bold}%
    \fi
    $\cdot\m@th$%
  }%
  \hidewidth
  \cr
  \vphantom{0}% correct depth of final symbol
}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\title{}

\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{specialdate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}.\twodigit{\THEMONTH}.\THEYEAR}
\date{\specialdate\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Bla...

\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

But that I want

[image]

How do I add a dot inside the zeros on the date?

Comment: Just use a font that has dots inside the zero.